# Create stack of child view controllers of root navigation controller from App Delegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, children

Starting from my `AppDelegate`, I create the following:

```
self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController"
                                                       bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                          initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

Would I be able to use the `addChildViewController:` method to make a tree of my view controllers?  So that when I navigate throughout my app, I can use the index in my navigation stack to pop/push to any view controller.  Unless that's not how it works.

Reason why I ask, I currently am able to successfully navigate throughout my entire app using the pop/push methods on my navigation stack, but there is one situation where I need to jump over one child(1) to the sub-child(2) of that child(1).

Imagine 1 button that pushes from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`.  And from `ViewController2`, there's another button that pushes to `ViewController3`.  However, in `ViewController1`, there's a second button, that when pressed, needs to push directly to `ViewController3`.

How can I do that?  Is what I described above possible?

I am using Xcode 7.1.2 and iOS 8.

Comment: And when you press back button on ViewController3 you should get to ViewController2?

Comment: Unless you did what Nikita ask, or else you don't need to create stack before hand, just create the vc when you are going to show it

Comment: To Nikita, yes.  I just implemented it now and getting to `ViewController3` from `ViewController1` via navigation push works, with `ViewController2` as child of `1` and parent of `3`.  However, I cannot pop to any other view controller when I jump-push to `3`.